# How To Make Slideshow Using ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm dynamically loading my image urls from database.

Here is my current code for the repeater to load the images

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="1200" Height="300" ImageURL='<%#Eval("ThumbnailPath")%>' class="slide" /></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

That is my .ASPX page where the image comes out but it only shows my images vertically stacked how do I make it into slideshow?

Here is my code To load the pictures to the repeater

```
    GallerySTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PPDB"].ConnectionString;
    GalleryCN = new SqlConnection(GallerySTR);

    string LoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM Albums";
    GalleryCN.Open();
    GalleryCMD = new SqlCommand(LoginQuery, GalleryCN);

    GalleryDA = new SqlDataAdapter(GalleryCMD);
    GalleryDS = new DataSet();
    GalleryDA.Fill(GalleryDS);
    Repeater1.DataSource = GalleryDS;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I can perfectly load the pictures but I can't seem to make it into slideshow. some javascript perhaps? or some technique or codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get this

[jQuery Slideshow](http://i-like-robots.github.io/jQuery-Slideshow/)

This will go in your aspx designer

```
<div class="slideshow" data-transition="crossfade" data-loop="true" data-skip="false">
        <ul class="carousel">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %>' alt="" width="440" height="200" />
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Bind your code to this repeater, and don't forget to include the script includes in the aspx page.

**UPDATE**

Add your required css files link in the head section of the html page.  You will need to adapt to your project.

```
<link href="Content/Slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And at the end of the body tag, you will add the js scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Slideshow.js"></script>
```